# Can we use class methods (which start with + sign) with instances of that class

Tags: objective-c, class-method

Just wondering if there is any way we can use class methods (i.e. +(void)mymethod ) with instance of that class?

Also is it possible to access instance variables in my class methods?

Answer (score 3):

No You cant invoke a static method with the instance. Static method can only invoked by using class name.

You cant access instance variables from static methods. Only static variables can be access.

Comment: To expand, you can't call a class method on an instance because the compiler will look for a instance method of that name and not find one. You could call [[instance class]classMethod] if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

> is any way we can use class methods (i.e. +(void)mymethod ) with instance of that class?

Well of course you can. The class nothing but an object that you can retrieve from the instance, so just go ahead and do it.

```
[[myInstance class] myClassMethod]
```

---

> is it possible to access instance variables in my class methods?

No, and for obvious reasons: it doesn't make any sense.

You're in a class method, to which instance would like you refer to? The last one created? The first one? As far as you know there might even not be an instance allocated. Let's try with an example

Here's a class declaration (just the interface will suffice)

```
@interface FancyClass : NSObject
@property NSString *name;
+ (void)myFancyClassMethod;
@end
```

Now let's declare a couple of instances

```
FancyClass *fancy1 = [FancyClass new];
fancy1.name = @"Hi I'm Fancy 1";
FancyClass *fancy2 = [FancyClass new];
fancy2.name = @"Hi I'm Fancy 2";
```

Now if you hypothetically could access the instance variables from `myFancyClassMethod`'s implementation, what value would you expect to read for `name`? Do you see the nonsense?

Answer (score 0):

An instance var belongs to an instance. Now if you can access instance var within a class method, which instance that instance var belongs to, among all the instances floating out there?